# Joomla 3 Login redirect - works in Login Module but does not working from component login view

Tags: redirect, authentication, joomla3.0

I am working on Joomla 3.x
I have a requirement to redirect to a new page after login.
I know there is an option in Login Module under module manager, where in we can specify "login Redirection Page". This is working perfectly fine. it is redirecting to the place where i wish to.

However, the issue is - 
Once User creates a new account ( i have disabled the registration process, so no email links activation is required) user is presented with a Login view (not from module) from component - com_users. Once credentials are supplied, instead of redirecting to the desired page i set in module manager, it goes to profile page of com_users component. 
index.php/component/users/?view=profile

I need your suggestions to change this default behavior. Is there any place where i can set the redirection page for component com_users, similar to how we have for Login Module? Do I need to go for Joomla core file coding changes? Or Do i need to create Plugin which can fire after OnLoginUser event?

Expecting suggestion from you guys.

Thanks and regards,
Gaurav Pandya

Answer (score 3):

In the menu item setup (menu item type -> login form) please check the options tab there is a field that you could set login redirect.

**EDIT:**

If your login is not connected to a menu please try make an override to:
components/com_users/views/login/tmpl/default_login.php
line 79:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo base64_encode($this->params->get('login_redirect_url', $this->form->getValue('return'))); ?>" />
```

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel. I know that option. it is working fine. The issue is with the USER component. Once you register(create a new account) you are presented with a Thank you message and login form. This login form is not from Login Module. It comes from User component. If we try to login it doesn't take us to the desired page (redirected page). I hope I have clearly placed my requirement. Thanks again.

Comment: Your edit worked for me. I think I prefer it to installing yet another plugin - for now, anyway! I guess I'll need to remember this when it comes to an upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is no need for a plugin or any template overrides.

If you're using a menu item to publish the login page then you simply need to add an absolute URL into the 'login redirect' field of the menu item itself (not the login module).

E.g. http://www.somesite.com/my-account
and not
/my-account

For some reason a relative url (/my-account) is counted as an external URL and is overriden in the controller which is why it's redirected to 'my-account/profile.

Hope this help somebody.